# Python Webscraping, how to navigate on a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am programming a program that should read out certain data from a website and only output certain data (data from a table). However, I ran into a problem. I wrote a program that logs into the website, but from that website I have to go to the next website and then open the document with the data. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can change the website and then open the document and read out the data.
Does anyone have any idea how I could get on there?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

User = ''
Pass = ''
LOGIN_URL = ''
LOGIN_API_URL = ''


def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    cookies = result.cookies
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
    auth_token = soup.find("input", {'name': 'logintoken'}).get('value')

    payload = {'username': User, 'password': Pass , 'logintoken':auth_token }

    result = session_requests.post(
    LOGIN_API_URL,
    data=payload,
    cookies=cookies
    )

    #Report successful login
    print("Login succeeded: ", result.ok)
    print("Status code:", result.status_code)
    print(result.text)

    #Get Data



    # Close Session
    requests.session().close()
    print('Session closed')

# Entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: After you log in, you should be able to use your session to go to the next page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should read into [Selenium with Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Since there is no specific URL or login details (which you shouldn't post here anyway) it would be quite hard for any of us to create a working example since we don't have anything to work with.

Try the using selenium from the link above and if you have any questions or run into any issues from there come back and ask that specific question.

BS4 and requests can be powerful but selenium emulates a web browser and lets you move through websites like a "human" would. Start there.

Comment: Thanks it works very well, but now i got the problem that i dont know how to get the data from the table.

Comment: @Oskar_GER No problem, I am glad it is (kinda) working for you! If this answer did help with your original question remember to select it as the answer for your question. If you also are having problems with your new code, create a new question with your new code. There are a lot of selenium questions around here and a LOT of people that can help you out!